# My magento module is not shown?

Tags: magento

I have created a new Magento module which is in

```
app/code/local/my_module/...
```

but when I goto magento backend I cant see my module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create an XML file in etc/modules/ to be able to see your Module in magento-backend

```
etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModuleName.xml
```

2- MyCompany_MyModuleName.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModuleName>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyCompany_MyModuleName>
 </modules>
</config>
```